# Search CSV and return field

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a csv file that I would like to reference based on user input. User would type in first and last name of an employee and I would like it to return The Payroll Department Number associated with that employee.  The 3 columns I need to work with are titled First, Last, Payroll Department Number. What am I doing wrong?

Here is what I have:

```
$csv = import-csv c:\employees.csv
$First = read-host 'What is the users first name?'
$Last = read-host 'What is the users last name?'
$csv | where {$_.last -eq $Last; $_.'First Name' -eq $First} |
  % "Payroll Department Number"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the semicolon in your `Where-Object` condition with an `-and` operator, and replace the `ForEach-Object` statement with a `Select-Object`:

```
$csv | Where-Object { $_.last -eq $Last -and $_.'First Name' -eq $First } |
  Select-Object -Expand 'Payroll Department Number'
```

Comment: Thank you!  Works great now.

Comment: If I wanted to write-host "Name Not found" if a match isn't made, what would I need to add? Ive tried different If/Else statements and not getting desired results.

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new or followup question: post a new question.